# Unable to find list of open source apps build using spring boot in internet

Tags: spring

I have searched the internet for hours and unable to find list of application built using Spring Boot.

Could someone let me know where i can see the list of applications built using Spring Boot?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need such a list? As it stands this question is off topic for SO and will eventually get closed. However maybe there's a real reason your asking that *is* on topic that we can help with

Comment: Looking for open source projects which has been used in real time for reference or to go through how they have developed using spring boot. Need some good working and proven project for reference...Please help me if you know atleast a few.

Comment: Any comments on this?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot is an open source framework. There is no comprehensive list of which applications are using it because there are probably hundreds of new public projects being created each day.

This does not even take into consideration all the projects that are internal corporate projects that wouldn't show up in such a list.

Comment: Looking for open source projects which has been used in real time for reference or to go through how they have developed using spring boot. Need some good working and proven project for reference...Please help me if you know atleast a few.

Comment: Any comments on this?